Cohomology of differentiable stacks: should the sheaf be fine?
I'm reading these Behrend's notes on cohomology of stacks, and I can't get over a detail in the fifth page.
Let $X_\bullet=(X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)$ be a Lie groupoid and let $\mathcal{N}$ be its nerve. By applying the $k$-differential forms (contravariant) functor $\Omega^k$ to the nerve $\mathcal{N}$ we get a semicosimplicial abelian group
$$\Omega^q(X_0)\rightrightarrows\Omega^q(X_1) \rightarrow\rightrightarrows \cdots$$
(sorry I can't stack three arrows)
that induces a cochain complex in the usual way. The author calls this cochain complex the "Cěch complex" and its cohomologies are called the "Cěch cohomologies".
The author proves that the Cěch cohomologies are Morita-invariant and the proof uses pretty explicitely the existence of partitions of unity in its first part, because it uses the "Generalized Mayer-Vietoris sequence" from Bott,Tu (page 94).
I have no problem with this proof. Then, the author states that for this proof to work, we don't necessarily need the contravariant functor $\Omega^q$, because any contravariant functor $F:\textbf{Man}\to \textbf{Ab}$ satisfying the following properties

$F$ is a sheaf when restricted to the category of open subsets of any manifold $M$ with inclusions of open sets,

the Cěch cohomologies (associated to the functor $F$) vanish on manifolds,


will do the job! But I don't see how can we replicate the "partition of unity argument" with such weak hyphothesis. Shouldn't we require $F$ to be a fine sheaf on any manifold?

Partitions of unity are necessary to prove the second bullet point (higher cohomology of fine sheaves on paracompact Hausdorff spaces vanishes).  If you impose it as a separate condition instead, there is no need to keep asking for fineness.

@DmitriPavlov Correct me if I'm wrong. Let $M$ be a manifold and $u(M)$ be its associated Lie groupoid. Clearly the faces of the nerve of $u(M)$ are identity maps, so the differential of the Cech complex of $u(M)$ is $0$ at the even degrees and the identity at the odd degrees. This implies that the higher cohomologies of $u(M)$ vanish: I didn't use partitions of unity. The partitions of unity are used to prove the higher cohomologies of the Cech groupoid vanish (not the cohomologies of manifolds).

The Čech cohomology mentioned in the second bullet point is defined as the Čech cohomology of any Lie groupoid that presents M, e.g., the one induced by an open cover of M.  It doesn't have to be the trivial groupoid on M.

@DmitriPavlov Thank you! I misunderstood the condition imposed by the author.
